# Probleme with empty items in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build 2d array with JS.

In a theater there is 26 lines, each one include 100 seats :

```
function theaterSeats() {
  let seats= new Array(26);
  for (let i = 1; i <= 26; i++){
    seats[i] = new Array(100);
    for (let j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
      seats[i][j] = `${i}-${j}`
    }
  }
  return seats;
}

console.log(theaterSeats());
```

The result is not far from what I expected, except that there is an empty item in each array... I don't understand why. Some help please ?

```
[
  <1 empty item>,
  [
    <1 empty item>, '1-1',  '1-2',  '1-3',
    '1-4',          '1-5',  '1-6',  '1-7',
    '1-8',          '1-9',  '1-10', '1-11'
```

(...................)

Thanks in advance for your answer ;).

Comment: Arrays indices in JavaScript start from 0. You know that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) solution

```js
const theaterSeats = [...Array(26)].map((_, i) => {
  return [...Array(100)].map((_, j) => `${i+1}-${j+1}`)
})

console.log(theaterSeats)
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays' index start from 0 that's why your first item is always empty because you have skipped index 0 and started your iteration from index 1. You need to fill your array starting from index 0!

The correct version of your code could be:

```js
function theaterSeats() {
  let seats= new Array(26);
  for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    seats[i] = new Array(100);
    for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      seats[i][j] = `${i + 1}-${j + 1}`
    }
  }
  return seats;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you're using 1 as the 1st index instead of 0, array index starts in 0, something like:

An array of 7 elements have those indexes: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. So when setting a value to a position you'll begin like: array[0] = 'some value', array[1] = 'some other value' ...

Here in your for loop you'll need to begin with i and j = 0. So it'll look like

```
function theaterSeats() {
  let seats= new Array(26);
  for (let i = 0; i <= 26; i++){
    seats[i] = new Array(100);
    for (let j = 0; j <= 100; j++) {
      seats[i][j] = `${i+1}-${j+1}`
    }
  }
  return seats;
}

console.log(theaterSeats());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply ;).

I found the solution before checking your answer. I did that and it's working :

```
function theaterSieges() {
  let siege = new Array(26);
  for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    siege[i] = new Array(100);
    for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      siege[i][j] = `${i+1}-${j+1}`
    }
  }
  return siege;
}

console.log(theaterSieges());
```

I will keep in mind your tips.

Thanks again ;)